# Include css file in richlet with zk

Tags: java, css, zk

I'm working on creating a view only with java in a ZK Richlet and I'm trying to include a css file in the Richlet but I didn't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to utilize the [`desktop-config`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Configuration_Reference/zk.xml/The_desktop-config_Element) element of your `zk.xml`. Especially the  `theme-uri` and `theme-provider-class` elements are used to apply additional style classes.

```
<desktop-config>
    <theme-uri>/to/your/css.css</theme-uri>
</desktop-config>
```

Another option - although not recommended by the class' [API](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.2/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/sys/PageCtrl.html) - is to use the [addBeforeHeadTags](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.2/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/sys/PageCtrl.html#addBeforeHeadTags%28java.lang.String%29) method of `PageCtrl`:

```
((PageCtrl)page).addBeforeHeadTags("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/to/your/css.css\" />");
```

Comment: great I tried the first solution and it's work.. but now how about including javaScript file?

Comment: See http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/General_Control/JavaScript_Packaging.